# Custom resource model (parameter) not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

So I have a basic resource for Basket:

```
Route::resource('basket', BasketController::class)->parameters([
    'basket' => 'product'
]);
```

Which points to a basic controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class BasketController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store product
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Product $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function store(Product $product): View
    {
        dd($product);
    }
}
```

My blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('basket.store', $product) }}" method="post" class="w-full">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="flex items-center button tertiary small">
        <svg class="h-5 w-5">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icons.svg#basket"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="text-xs font-semibold ml-2">
            {{ __('Add to basket') }}
        </span>
    </button>
</form>
```

I am expecting the route in my blade to be `basket/1/` rather than `basket?3` but that causes the `$product` to be empty in my controller... How come? I am purposefully using the `Product::class` model rather than `Basket::class`... to my knowledge this should work but doesn't seem to?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what's going on:
In a resource controller, using standard naming conventions, a store route does not expect a parameter.
If you insist and send it a forced one like route('basket.store',['basket' => $product]) you will get an URL like basket?basket=3

Please verify with php artisan route:list the parameters expected with each of the resource controller's routes.

You may get your expected result if you use @method('put') inside your  below your @csrf in your blade file.